# Observable Collection sum the colunm as row added WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I am working on project.I use datagrid to fill the empty "Observable Collection" and it is working as expected.the main problem is that i want to calculate "Total Price" of the "product" when i enter in the datagrid view.As the "Pricesrc" is binded to a textbox that need to display "Total Price".Now how i accomplish this task.Help will be appreciated.

Ths is my product class.

```
public class product_data
{
   private String _Name;
   private String _Brand;
   private String _Price;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    public string Brand
    {
        get { return _Brand; }
        set { _Brand = value; }
    }

    public string Price
    {
        get { return _Price; }
        set
        {
            _Price = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel Class.

```
 public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    public int Pricesrc
    {
        set;get;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<product_data> listsrc;
    public ObservableCollection<product_data> product_data
    {
        get { return listsrc; }
        set
        {
            listsrc = value; 
        }
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        listsrc = new ObservableCollection<Pages.Product.product_data>();
    }

     public  event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void onPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new  PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid  Background="#C82C2C2C">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightGray" Margin="150,60,150,60">
        <StackPanel.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="44"/>
        </StackPanel.Effect>
        <StackPanel Background="#FF886AF0" Height="80">
            <TextBlock Text="Bill" FontSize="25" FontWeight="SemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,35,0,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_Total" ToolTip="Total" Text="{Binding Pricesrc}" Height="50" Background="White" Foreground="#FFB6B2B2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="630" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource flat_ui_textbox}" GotFocus="textboxes_gotFocus" LostFocus="textboxes_lostFocus"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_advance" ToolTip="Advance" Text="Advance" Height="50" Background="White" Foreground="#FFB6B2B2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="315" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource flat_ui_textbox}" GotFocus="textboxes_gotFocus" LostFocus="textboxes_lostFocus"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_pending" ToolTip="Pending" Text="Pending" Height="50" Background="White" Foreground="#FFB6B2B2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="315" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource flat_ui_textbox}" GotFocus="textboxes_gotFocus" LostFocus="textboxes_lostFocus"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_date" ToolTip="Date" Text="Date" Height="50" Background="White" Foreground="#FFB6B2B2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="475" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource flat_ui_textbox}" GotFocus="textboxes_gotFocus" LostFocus="textboxes_lostFocus"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="48,0,0,0" Text="Is Paid" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Foreground="#FF818181"/>
            <CheckBox Margin="16,0,0,0" Height="35" Width="35"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource flat_ui_checkboxes}"></CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <GroupBox Header="Product" Margin="150,35,150,0" Foreground="#FF7E7E7E" FontSize="24" FontWeight="DemiBold">
            <DataGrid x:Name="product_grid" ItemsSource="{Binding product_data,Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Height=" 350"   Background="White" Width="973.5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Brand" Binding="{Binding Brand,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price,Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
        <Button Width="200" Height="55" Background="#FF2DCC70" Margin="0,0,0,0" Template="{DynamicResource flat_add_green_btn}" Command="{Binding Add_Customer_Command}" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should use `PropertyChanged` event when your `Pricesrc` changes:

```
private int _Pricesrc;
public int Pricesrc
{
    get { return _Pricesrc; }
    set { _Pricesrc = value; onPropertyChanged(nameof(Pricesrc)); }
}
```

This is required so when you set total binding is updated.

Now, in order to update `Pricesrc` when your collection changes (when item is added or removed) you should handle event of the collection that notifies exactly about that - CollectionChanged https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx

In constructor add event handler:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    listsrc = new ObservableCollection<Pages.Product.product_data>();
    listsrc.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}

private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Pricesrc = listsrc.Sum(prod => prod.Price);
}
```

Edit: If you want to update total price when price of existing product is changed, you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your `product_data` class and raise event when `Price` property is changed similar to what I did here with `Pricesrc` property. Then handle that event and update total price.

Comment: Thanks for response,It solve the problem but one thing is left that "The last row of grid's price is not added.... any solution??...and can you explain what "Pricesrc = listsrc.Sum(prod => prod.Price)" really do...Thanks agai.

Comment: Also when I click on the empty column the event is triggered but it is not triggered when the row is added.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that Price property is string. You should convert it to appropriate numeric type (like int or double) when summing (or change type of property completely).
Sum basically sums value of given property for while IEnumerable<T> (ie. List, array etc.).